# Negative key in binary search method in Java

Tags: java

What does it mean when the second argument is negative. I'm looking at a piece of code that searches for a key in an array. But what does a negative key mean ?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int j = Arrays.binarySearch(a, -a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It means its look for a number which it the negative of a number in the array already.

This could be a positive key. For example, if `a[0]` is `-10`, it will look for `10` in the same array.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%29), `key` is the value (in the array) to be searched for.  Negating the argument just searches for its negation within the array!